# Is it possible to run Azure Function app with SSL locally?

Tags: azure, macos, ssl, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure function app. It works well with HTTP locally. Also it works well on production. I am trying to run it with HTTPS locally. I created a certificate but it's still showing a certificate error on the browser. I tried to add my certificate to KeyChain Access as well but the result is the same.

How can I run my function with an SSL certificate locally?

I'am trying to access my service from my mobile app but android is not allowing me to call a HTTP endpoint.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The command line arguments need to be set correctly, and then the Azure Functions can be started in Visual Studio with HTTPS and take advantage of the break point debugging without having to attach the func process in Visual Studio.

1. **Install the tools for local Azure Function development**:
   Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer
   Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator
   [Install the Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#install-the-azure-functions-core-tools)
   Or
   `npm install -g azure-functions-core-tools`
2. **Install the Azure Functions Visual Studio Extensions**

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools need to be installed as an extension in Visual Studio.

[image]

3. **Configure the Azure Functions project to use HTTPS**

Create a certificate and add this to the operating system.

`openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out server.pass.key 2048`

``` openssl rsa -passin pass:x -``in ``` `server.pass.key -out server.key`

``` openssl req -``new ``` `-key server.key -out server.csr`

``` openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -``in ``` `server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt`

or

`New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName` ``` "server.com"``, ``` `"server.com"` `-CertStoreLocation` `"cert:\LocalMachine\My"`

`Get the thumbprint` `for` `later use`

`$mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String` `"1111"` `-Force -AsPlainText`

``` Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\``"thumbprint from above" ``` `| Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\server.pfx -Password $mypwd`

4. Copy the `pfx` file to the Function project and then configure the properties to copy this to the output.

[image]

5. Configure the command line arguments for Debug.
6. The application arguments starts with  **host**  in Visual Studio and not `func`! This would be  **func** in the command line.

[image]

Or just set this in the launchSettings.json

```
{

"profiles"``: {
"FunctionApp1": {
"commandName":` "Project",
"commandLineArgs": "host start --useHttps --cert \"server.pfx\" --password \"1111\""
        }
    }
}
```

When you start the Azure Function project with Visual Studio, the HTTPS URL will be used. This can be checked in the command line window which opens up after starting. Break point debugging is now possible as we started from Visual Studio.

[image]

If you start this from the console using the  **func start –useHttps –cert “server.pfx” –password “1111”**, you need to attach the func process for break point debugging for using Visual Studio.